# What is the difference between a method object and a function object in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I am reading the official python documentation on python classes here: https://docs.python.org/release/3.8.5/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=class.

In section 9.3.2, following an example of class definition

```py
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345

    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

there is a remark:

> So in our example, `x.f` is a valid method reference, since `MyClass.f` is a function, but `x.i` is not, since `MyClass.i` is not. But `x.f` is not the same thing as `MyClass.f` — it is a method object, not a function object.

I am a bit confused about the difference between a *method object* and a *function object*. To me they are both some object that can be called. After more reading, I think the difference is:

- A *function object* must receive a full list of argument(s) as in its definition.
- A *method object* receives some arguments implicitly, for example, the `x.f` method above, when called, receives the instance `x` implicitly as its first argument `self`.

I have some questions:

- Is this the correct understanding of the difference between a method object and function object?
- Is this the sole difference between them?
- Are there any other, maybe more complicated, examples that illustrates the difference?

Comment: Function objects are [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), their `__get__` methods return a method object, which basically just partially applied version of itself (with the instance as the first argument). So, `some_instance.some_method` invokes the descriptor protocol, the `__get__` method of the function is invoked, and `some_instance.some_method` is evaluated as that method object, so ehwn you do `some_isntance.some_method()` the method object is actually being called. Note, this happens every time, so `some_instance.some_method is not some_instace.some_method`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! This is very clear. One small thing, do you mean in the last sentence `some_instance.some_method` is not `some_class.some_method`?